# DataTable Combine Values and Remove Source Rows

Tags: c#, datatable

I have created a Datatable and I'm trying to reduce the number of rows. I was able to find a way to check if a testID exists in a table and merge hostnames but I am not sure how to remove the source rows.

Example `dtOrginal`:

```
testID passFail description hostname
1ab    pass     ....        alpha
1ab    pass     ....        bravo
1ab    fail     ....        charlie
1ac    pass     ....        alpha
```

Example Current Result:

```
testID passFail description hostname
1ab    pass     ....        alpha, bravo
1ab    pass     ....        bravo
1ab    fail     ....        charlie
1ac    pass     ....        alpha
```

What I'm trying to get

```
testID passFail description hostname
1ab    pass     ....        alpha, bravo
1ab    fail     ....        charlie
1ac    pass     ....        alpha
```

Here is my current function to merge the hostnames and testIDs when neccessary

```
DataTable dtReducedColumns = CombineHostnames(dtOrinal).Copy();

private static DataTable CombineHostnames(DataTable dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtOrginal.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            bool isDupe = false;
            string a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l;

            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                a = dtOrginal.Rows[i][0].ToString(); //testID
                b = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                c = dtOrginal.Rows[i][1].ToString(); //passFail
                d = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString();
                g = dtOrginal.Rows[i][2].ToString(); //description
                h = dt.Rows[j][2].ToString();
                if (a == b && c == d && g == h)
                {
                    e = dt.Rows[j][10].ToString();
                    f = dtOrginal.Rows[i][10].ToString(); //hostname
                    k = dtOrginalRows[i][8].ToString(); //source
                    l = dt.Rows[j][8].ToString();
                    if (!e.Contains(f))
                        dt.Rows[j][10] = e + ", " + f; //combine hostnames
                    if (!k.Contains(l))
                        dt.Rows[j][8] = k + ", " + l; //combine sources
                    isDupe = true;
                    //tried adding dt.Rows[j].Delete() here
                    //tried adding dt.Rows[j-1].Delete() here get -1 error
                    break;
                } 
               //tried adding dt.Rows[j].Delete() here
               //tried adding dt.Rows[j-1].Delete() here get -1 error
            }
            //tried adding dt.Rows[j].Delete() here
            //tried adding dt.Rows[j-1].Delete() here get -1 error

            if (!isDupe)
            {
                dt.ImportRow(dtOrginal.Rows[i]);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

The places where I have tried to delete the rows either throws an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception or returns a table similar to `dtOrginal`.

For reference, here is the entire DataTable I'm working with:

```
dtChecklistFindingsTable = new DataTable();                                  //Column Number
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("testID", typeof(string));              // 0
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("passFail", typeof(string));            // 1
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("description", typeof(string));         // 2
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("vulLevel", typeof(string));            // 3
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("recommendation", typeof(string));      // 4
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("comments", typeof(string));            // 5
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("title", typeof(string));               // 6
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("testCheck", typeof(string));           // 7
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("source", typeof(string));              // 8
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));                // 9
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("hostName", typeof(string));            // 10
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("os", typeof(string));                  // 11
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("ipAddr", typeof(string));              // 12
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("stigLevel", typeof(string));           // 13
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("stigSeverity", typeof(string));        // 14
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("sarStatus", typeof(string));           // 15
dtChecklistFindingsTable.Columns.Add("iaControl", typeof(string));           // 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use-case for `Linq-To-DataTable`, especially `Enumerable.GroupBy` +  `String.Join`:

```
private static DataTable CombineHostnames(DataTable dtOrginal)
{
    DataTable tblresult = dtOrginal.Clone(); // empty table, same columns
    var rowGroups = dtOrginal.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => new
        {
            Id = row.Field<string>("testId"),
            passFail = row.Field<string>("passFail")
        });

    foreach (var group in rowGroups)
    {
        DataRow row = tblresult.Rows.Add(); // already added now
        row.SetField("testId", group.Key.Id);
        row.SetField("passFail", group.Key.passFail);
        row.SetField("description", group.First()["description"]);  // the first?
        string hostNames = String.Join(", ", group.Select(r => r.Field<string>("hostname")));
        row.SetField("hostname", hostNames);
    }
    return tblresult;
}
```

You can add the other columns in the same way i've already added `description` by simply using the first of each group or by another logic.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! Made a couple minor edits since the testID is alphanumeric I changed it to a string and there was an extra space in `SetField("description"...)` that I removed.

Comment: Is there a way to do a check before joining the string? In other words some fields I expect to have the same ID but come from a different source and I would like to merge the sources, but only have unique sources?

Comment: I tried using .Distinct() but it gave me this `System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__63`1[System.Char]` several times

Comment: Maybe you could ask another question for this and someone else can help.  I'm in holidays now :)

Comment: egh, I just created a separate helper method.