# C# Linq get values from column B if column A matches

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Based on the table below, I'd like to use Linq to get all of the device names associated with Test ID `1a` and store them in a list, is this possible? Assuming that is not always known which Test ID will be listed more than once.

```
Test ID    DeviceName
1a         dev1
1b         dev2
1a         dev2
1c         dev1
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. You ask and show examples about `TestId` and `DeviceName` but then show code with many other fields. Can you better explain what you'd like to do?

Comment: The concept seems pretty clear...I have a table with multiple test ids and want to gather all the hostnames associated by test id; it shouldn't make a difference if the code and example table are the same or not

Comment: Why are you grouping by 2 fields and adding rows to the DataTable - it confuses me a bit. I can answer on how to group and then concatenate the values but the rest of the code makes me unsure if that is what you want

Comment: that was based on an answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38791885/1072681 I'm not sure if there is a different/better way...

Comment: I executed the code above with only the 2 columns you specified in the data examples and it seems to be exactly how you want it..

Comment: changed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is read all the values from column B then the following query is all you should need:

```
string testID;
// set testID from somewhere (user input, config file, another query etc.)

var results = dataTable.Where(t => t.Id == testID).Select(t => t.DeviceName).ToList();
```

`results` will be of type `List<string>`.

Comment: I should iterate that it will not always be known what the testID will be

Comment: @Chris - in that just replace the string with a variable and use that.